# Query is very slow, can i combine or optimized this

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

Good day,

I have a query that takes a long time and I can't figure out how to optimize it.

```
SELECT 
a.*,
(SELECT 
        COUNT(*)
    FROM
       sp_produkte
    WHERE
        bemerkung = '9' AND prodId = a.id) as count
FROM
   produktions_liste a
WHERE
    sp_id = 1
        AND DATE(endzeit) = CURDATE() - 11
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

This query only checks how often something with the same prodId was posted in another table. Is it possible to pre-select this data for the same day in order not to have to search through the entire table in each row?

Table produktions_liste

| id | prodId | somestuff |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | *** |
| 2 | 2 | *** |
| 3 | 3 | *** |
| 4 | 4 | *** |

Table sp_produkte

| id | prodId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 |

What I would like

| id | prodId | somestuff | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | *** | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | *** | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | *** | 1 |
| 4 | 4 | *** | 0 |

Comment: Please read [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)

Comment: Thx and sry for that! My bad English is not exactly helpful.

I hope it's better now

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  I at least need to see the datatype of `endzeit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would rephrase the predicate:

```
AND DATE(endzeit) = CURDATE() - 11
```

to:

```
AND endzeit >= CURDATE() - 11 and endzeit < CURDATE() - 10
```

This will allow the usage of the index:

```
create index ix1 on produktions_liste (sp_id, endzeit);
```

Second, I would consider adding an index for the scalar subquery in the select list. This one could take the form:

```
create index ix2 on sp_produkte (bemerkung, prodId);
```

This second index will make scans much faster on the secondary table.

Try both changes (together or separately). If the query is still slow, please post the execution plan.

Comment: Thx a lot! I would not have thought that an index alone would make so much difference

Answer (score 0):

Composite **indexes** needed:

```
a:  INDEX(sp_id, endzeit, id)
sp_produkte:  INDEX(bemerkung, prodId)
```

The -1 is probably **wrong**.  If `endzeit` is type **`DATE`**, then change to simply

```
AND endzeit = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 11 DAY
```

If it is a `DATETYPE`, then do

```
AND endzeit >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 11 DAY
AND endzeit  < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 10 DAY
```

(This will also work for `DATE`.)

Even better *may* be to **reformulate**:

```
SELECT a.*,
       counts.ct AS 'count'
    FROM ( SELECT sp.prodId, COUNT(*) AS ct
            FROM  sp_produkte AS sp
            WHERE  sp.bemerkung = '9'
         ) AS counts
    JOIN produktions_liste AS a  ON a.id = counts.prodId
    WHERE  a.sp_id = 1
      AND endzeit >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 11 DAY
      AND endzeit  < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 10 DAY
    ORDER BY  a.id DESC
    LIMIT  20;
```

For further discussion, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`